# Chef - expressions in `kitchen.yml` attributes?

Tags: configuration, chef-infra

In [kitchen.yml](https://docs.chef.io/config_yml_kitchen.html), I would like to have an expression in the `attributes:` part. However it seems it is just a static file with literal values.

Is it somehow possible to have the values in `attributes:` evaluated?

The reason for that need is that I have some `node.default`s in `defaults.rb`, and some of them are URLs at the same host, say, `http:foo.org/service`. And in the `kitchen.yml` I want to parametrize the host. So I would have:

```
... 
attributes: { serviceX_baseURL: "http://bar.org/service" }
```

I want the override to happen with `kitchen_*.yml` override and not `attributes/*.rb` (that would be easier) because the override happens later in the process, after the main `kitchen.yml` file is already generated.

Any practical solutions for that are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Erb formatting in the `.kitchen.yml` for some very simplistic templating, but you didn't really give a concrete example. Chances are you should not do this, generally parameterizing both the code and tests on the same input means the tests are brittle or not testing what you think they are.